# When running optimize command, it rebuilds the table, so how much extra space is required in the database?

Tags: mysql, optimization, innodb

Should I have enough space for another copy of the table?
e.g table i want to optimise is 400mb 
database storage left is 200mb.

Will this work or do i need to have database storage of greater than 400mb?

Comment: From my practice - optimize may need up to ~ triple size. I don't know why...

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS` and the reason for doing the `OPTIMIZE` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table'`.  There may be a workaround.